# Shell script wait command never ends

Tags: android, linux, macos, shell, sh

I am writing a script file to run Android test cases from the shell, I have some `Android ADB commands` to run test cases in the script file to execute and have `wait` to wait first set of test cases ends once the first set ends then starts seconds.

Script file: snippet

```
#!/bin/bash
# set up code

#First set of test cases
adb -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument -w com.android.demo.app.tests1/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner &
adb -s emulator-5556 shell am instrument -w com.android.demo.app.tests2/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner &
wait # Second set test cases does not started because this **wait** never ends

#Second set of test cases
adb -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument -w com.android.demo.app.tests3/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner &
adb -s emulator-5556 shell am instrument -w com.android.demo.app.tests4/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner &
wait

echo '--------- Test cases done --------------'
```

if I run the script its run-first set (test1 and test2) cases executed and the wait never ends to start the second set of test case
But the Android studio (IDE for Android) says test cases completed for test1 and test2 that is first set.
Note: ADB the runs the test cases on Android Emulator.
Kindly help me on why I am not getting wait ends.

Comment: `wait` won't exit both copies of `adb` do (and also any other background processes started earlier in the "set up code" elided). It's part of your onus in asking this question to demonstrate that `adb` *has* exited, and thus that the shell's behavior is in any way unexpected. Also part of your onus to prove that none of the "set up code" creates other jobs-table entries referring to jobs that are still running, and thus also still liable to be `wait` targets.

Answer (score 1):

I tested using the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set 1
ls -la &
ls -la &
wait # wait here

#set 2
pwd &
pwd &
wait # wait here
```

The code ran perfectly as expected, no stoppages or errors.

<strike>Please try running test3 and test4 without running test1 and test2, see if this helps.</strike>

EDIT: Also, from another answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124106/shell-script-wait-for-background-command) You should be able to capture the PID (processID) of the previous command, and use that PID as wait parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`wait` waits for all *children* of the current shell.  You probably have a child forked off before you start forking off your test cases as shown in the example above.  Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 40 &  # something unrelated you forgot to mention

# test case set 1:
sleep 5 &   # first test case
sleep 7 &   # second test case
wait  # this now will wait for the two test cases _AND_ the sleep 40 from above.
```

Sometimes the "unrelated" forked off stuff is not easy to spot, so don't be hasty.

If this is the reason for your problem, you can probably fix it by using a different shell to spawn off the other child like so:

```
(sleep 40 &)  # use a different shell to spawn off the child
```